# executing methods with dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I would like to use dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: to check how long since the app was last used, or something to that effect where I can send requests to my DB every 4 hrs or so but am not sure how dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow should be used?

The reason for using this would be in order to check if the users data version is up to date every 4/8 hrs or something along those lines.. maybe checked ever time the user accesses the app if thats possible... this would allow me to execute any methods that might need to be executed in order to get the users data up to date etc.

Comment: just store the time the app was launched or put into the background and check the difference between the current time and the stored date when you re launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

When you first launch the app, and everytime afterwards that you do a database refresh, store that database refresh time (e.g. in NSUserDefaults).

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastDatabaseRefreshTime"];
```

Then whenever the app becomes active, check if its more than 4 hours since the last database refresh time.  So in your

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSDate *dbRefreshDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastDatabaseRefreshTime"];
    dbRefreshDatePlus4hrs = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(4*60*60) sinceDate:dbRefreshDate];

    NSDate *nowTime = [NSDate date];
    if ([dbRefreshDatePlus4hrs compare:nowTime] == NSOrderedAscending) {
          // Its more than 4 hours since the last refresh so
          // add code to call for another database refresh here
    }
}
```